# .Net Transaction Lock Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a weird issue with Transaction locking and I cannot point out where the issue is coming.

Our client reported that they cannot use one page of the system and it was timing out. This page executes a stored procedure which involves CTE on it but no transactions at all. See my stored procedure below:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[X_WMS_GET_SALESORDERS_CUSTOM] 
@SelectedLocations VARCHAR(100) = null,
@FromDueDate DateTime= NULL,
@ToDueDate DateTime = NULL,
@SearchTerm VARCHAR(200) = NULL,

-- Dynamic filters
-- * Display name will be the parameter name without the @FILTER_ and underscores(_) are replaced by white space( ).
-- * BIT datatype is the equivalent of boolean or char(1) 'Y' or 'N'. This will display a Yes/No dropdown selection on UI.
@FILTER_Order_Date_from DATETIME = NULL,
@FILTER_Order_Date_to DATETIME = NULL,
@FILTER_Account VARCHAR(200) = NULL,
@FILTER_Locked BIT = NULL,
@FILTER_Stocks_Ready BIT = NULL,
@FILTER_Zones VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,

-- Pagination parameters
@START INT = 0,
@LENGTH INT = 0, -- // 0 = ALL
@SEARCH VARCHAR(250) = '', 
@SORTCOLUMN VARCHAR(250) = 'Order No',
@SORTDIRECTION INT = 0 -- // ASC = 0, DESC <> 0
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @ZONEDESC VARCHAR(50)

SELECT @ZONEDESC = X_DESCRIPTION FROM X_WMS_ZONES WHERE X_ZONE_ID = @FILTER_Zones;
-- select * from X_WMS_SALESORD_VW

WITH TEMPCTE_RESULTS as (

    SELECT '' AS [__HiddenColumns__|ACCNO|LOCNO|]

        ,SH.SEQNO AS [Order No] 
        ,DR.ACCNO
        ,DR.NAME AS Account
        ,SL.LOCATION as [LOCNO]
        ,MAX(SLOC.LNAME) AS Location
        ,SH.ORDERDATE AS [Order Date]
        ,SH.DUEDATE AS [Due Date]            
        ,CASE WHEN RECORDID IS NULL THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END AS [Locked]
        ,CASE WHEN SUM(ISNULL(BA.SOH,0) - ISNULL(BA.TOPICK, 0)) > 0 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS [Stocks Ready]

        ,STUFF((SELECT ', ' + _XZ.X_DESCRIPTION
            FROM SALESORD_LINES _SL 
            LEFT JOIN (SELECT * from(select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY StockCode ORDER BY Preference ASC) AS rn FROM  X_WMS_BIN_ASSIGNMENT  WITH(NOLOCK)) BAIN   where rn=1  ) _BA ON _BA.STOCKCODE = _SL.STOCKCODE
            LEFT JOIN dbo.X_WMS_BIN_LOCS AS _BL WITH(NOLOCK) ON _BL.BINID = _BA.BINID 
            LEFT JOIN dbo.X_WMS_ZONES AS _XZ WITH(NOLOCK) ON _XZ.X_ZONE_ID = _BL.ZONEID
            WHERE     (_SL.HDR_SEQNO = SH.SEQNO)
            GROUP BY _XZ.X_DESCRIPTION
            ORDER BY _XZ.X_DESCRIPTION FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('(./text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '') AS Zones

        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY 
            CASE WHEN @SORTCOLUMN = 'SEQNO' AND @SORTDIRECTION = 0 THEN SH.SEQNO END ASC, 
            CASE WHEN @SORTCOLUMN = 'SEQNO' AND @SORTDIRECTION <> 0 THEN SH.SEQNO END DESC, 
            CASE WHEN @SORTCOLUMN = 'NAME' AND @SORTDIRECTION = 0 THEN DR.NAME END ASC,
            CASE WHEN @SORTCOLUMN = 'NAME' AND @SORTDIRECTION <> 0 THEN DR.NAME END DESC, 
            CASE WHEN @SORTCOLUMN = 'LOCNAME' AND @SORTDIRECTION = 0 THEN MAX(SLOC.LNAME) END ASC,
            CASE WHEN @SORTCOLUMN = 'LOCNAME' AND @SORTDIRECTION <> 0 THEN MAX(SLOC.LNAME) END DESC, 
            CASE WHEN @SORTCOLUMN = 'ORDERDATE' AND @SORTDIRECTION = 0 THEN SH.ORDERDATE END ASC,
            CASE WHEN @SORTCOLUMN = 'ORDERDATE' AND @SORTDIRECTION <> 0 THEN SH.ORDERDATE END DESC, 
            CASE WHEN @SORTCOLUMN = 'DUEDATE' AND @SORTDIRECTION = 0 THEN SH.DUEDATE END ASC,
            CASE WHEN @SORTCOLUMN = 'DUEDATE' AND @SORTDIRECTION <> 0 THEN SH.DUEDATE END DESC,
            CASE WHEN @SORTCOLUMN = 'LOCKED' AND @SORTDIRECTION = 0 THEN CASE WHEN RECORDID IS NULL THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END END ASC,
            CASE WHEN @SORTCOLUMN = 'LOCKED' AND @SORTDIRECTION <> 0 THEN CASE WHEN RECORDID IS NULL THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END END DESC,
            CASE WHEN @SORTCOLUMN = 'STOCKS READY' AND @SORTDIRECTION = 0 THEN CASE WHEN SUM(ISNULL(BA.SOH,0) - ISNULL(BA.TOPICK, 0)) > 0 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END END ASC,
            CASE WHEN @SORTCOLUMN = 'STOCKS READY' AND @SORTDIRECTION <> 0 THEN CASE WHEN SUM(ISNULL(BA.SOH,0) - ISNULL(BA.TOPICK, 0)) > 0 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END END DESC,
            SH.SEQNO ASC
        ) AS ROWNUM
        ,COUNT(*) OVER() AS TotalCount
        ,COUNT(*) OVER() AS TotalFilteredCount

    FROM dbo.SALESORD_HDR AS SH 

        INNER JOIN dbo.DR_ACCS AS DR WITH(NOLOCK) ON DR.ACCNO = SH.ACCNO 
        INNER JOIN dbo.SALESORD_LINES AS SL WITH(NOLOCK) ON SL.HDR_SEQNO = SH.SEQNO AND SL.UNSUP_QUANT > 0 
        INNER JOIN STOCK_ITEMS SI WITH(NOLOCK) ON SI.STOCKCODE = SL.STOCKCODE
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.OBJECT_LOCK WITH(NOLOCK) ON dbo.OBJECT_LOCK.OBJECT_ID = 'Order' AND dbo.OBJECT_LOCK.RECORDID = SH.SEQNO 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN  dbo.X_WMS_PICK_DETAILS PD WITH(NOLOCK) ON PD.ORDERNO = SL.HDR_SEQNO AND PD.SOLINEID = SL.SOLINEID
        INNER JOIN dbo.STOCK_LOCATIONS AS SLOC WITH(NOLOCK) ON SLOC.X_WMS_USE = 1 AND SLOC.LOCNO = SL.LOCATION 
        --LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.X_WMS_SALESORD_LINES_STOCKQTYAVAIL_VW AS SOLSQA ON SOLSQA.HDR_SEQNO = SH.SEQNO 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * from(select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY StockCode ORDER BY Preference ASC) AS rn FROM  X_WMS_BIN_ASSIGNMENT  WITH(NOLOCK)) BAIN   where rn=1  ) BA ON BA.STOCKCODE = SL.STOCKCODE
        INNER JOIN X_WMS_BIN_LOCS BL WITH(NOLOCK) ON BL.BINID= BA.BINID AND BL.LOCATION = SL.LOCATION
            WHERE  1=1
        AND (SH.STATUS IN (0, 1)) 
        AND (SH.ONHOLD <> 'Y') 
        AND (SH.LAST_UPDATED < DATEADD(SECOND, - 5, GETDATE())) 
        AND (SL.ORD_QUANT > 0) 
        AND (SL.LINETYPE <> 2) 
        AND (SL.STOCKCODE <> SL.LINKED_STOCKCODE or (SI.STATUS <> 'L'))

        AND (@SelectedLocations='0' OR @SelectedLocations IS NULL OR @SelectedLocations = '' OR SL.LOCATION IN (SELECT ID FROM StringToIntList(@SelectedLocations,',')))
        AND (@FromDueDate IS NULL OR SH.DUEDATE >= @FromDueDate)
        AND (@ToDueDate IS NULL OR SH.DUEDATE <= @ToDueDate)
        AND (@SearchTerm IS NULL 
            OR CONVERT(VARCHAR, SH.SEQNO) LIKE '%' + @SearchTerm + '%'
            OR CONVERT(VARCHAR,DR.ACCNO) LIKE '%' + @SearchTerm + '%'
            OR DR.NAME LIKE '%' + @SearchTerm + '%')
        --AND SL.LOCATION IN( SELECT LOCNO FROM STOCK_LOCATIONS WHERE X_WMS_USE = 1 and X_WMS_INCLUDEONPICK= 1)

        -- Dynamic filters
        AND (@FILTER_Order_Date_from IS NULL OR SH.ORDERDATE >= @FILTER_Order_Date_from)
        AND (@FILTER_Order_Date_to IS NULL OR SH.ORDERDATE <= @FILTER_Order_Date_to)
        AND (@FILTER_Account IS NULL OR DR.NAME LIKE '%' + @FILTER_Account + '%')
        AND (@FILTER_Locked IS NULL OR CASE WHEN RECORDID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END = @FILTER_Locked)


        --AND (@ZONES IS NULL OR SLSZ.STOCKZONES LIKE '%' + @ZONEDESC + '%')
        AND (PD.PICKQTY IS NULL OR(PD.PICKQTY < SL.ORD_QUANT ) OR (PD.PICKQTY=0 and PD.QTYREGISTER=0))
        GROUP BY SH.SEQNO, DR.ACCNO, DR.NAME, SL.LOCATION, SH.ORDERDATE, SH.DUEDATE, dbo.OBJECT_LOCK.RECORDID
        HAVING (SUM(SL.ORD_QUANT) - SUM(SL.SUP_QUANT) - SUM(SL.BKORD_QUANT) - SUM(ISNULL(PD.PICKQTY, 0)) > 0)
        AND (@FILTER_Stocks_Ready IS NULL OR CASE WHEN SUM(ISNULL(BA.SOH,0) - ISNULL(BA.TOPICK, 0)) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = @FILTER_Stocks_Ready)
)

--

SELECT _TR.*
INTO #TMP
FROM TEMPCTE_RESULTS _TR
WHERE 1=1
    AND (ISNULL(@LENGTH, 0) = 0 OR ROWNUM BETWEEN @START + 1 AND (@START + @LENGTH))
ORDER BY ROWNUM

IF(ISNULL(@FILTER_Zones,'') != '')
BEGIN
    UPDATE #TMP SET ZONES = @ZONEDESC 
END
SELECT * FROM #TMP

DROP TABLE #TMP


END
```

While the page is still down I tried running the stored procedure manually on SQL Management and executes within 1 or 2 second with no problem. I am using ASP.Net MVC to display the result of this stored procedure.

I restarted the server but the issue still persist. the only way I was able to resolve it was to modify any line on the stored procedure execute it and undo the changes and execute again then it magically resolves the issue.

Has anyone encountered this? Any help would be greatly appreciated since I was ask to report tomorrow what just happened and I need something to say on our Meeting :(

TIA

Comment: Show us how you call the sp from your C# code. Also show us how you call it from SQL Management.

Comment: Does running `sp_recompile` make the issue go away? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-recompile-transact-sql

Comment: I am thinking it was on the #tmp that causes deadlock from within the same connection when it is called by the .Net.

Comment: BTW, during the time the page was down I also tried changing the USER ID on my connection string for my hope that it will execute now on different session and leaving any deadlock from the previous connection but unfortunately the error still persisted.

Comment: If you believe that #tmp is an issue, then don't have it auto-create it using SELECT INTO. Instead, use CREATE TABLE and insert into that. I doubt that is the cause though.

Comment: Are you able to answer my earlier questions?

Answer (score 0):

1. On some places, you have used "select *", select the required column only.
   2.Monitor your query from SQL profiler or activity monitor when it is hit from page.
   3.If you are facing deadlock, monitor it from SQL profiler to know exact reason.